# return response from php to jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to add a like/dislike button to my web, but I've got some problems with the ajax. Everything works find, but I can't figure out how to return the php response to the original page, and I've tried almost everything I came up with.

Here is a piece of my javascript code:

```
$( "#dislike" ).click(function() {

var action = "2";
$.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             data: { action: action, llista: llista}, 
             url: 'like.php'
         });
   });
```

And here the php code (like.php) :

```
$selectpunct = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM llistes WHERE ID = '$IDllista' ") or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectpunct)){
$punct = $row ['punct']; }

if ($action == 1) {
    $noupunct = $punct+1;
}else if ($action ==2) {
    $noupunct = $punct-1;
}
echo $noupunct;

    $canvipunct= mysql_query ("UPDATE llistes SET punct = '".$noupunct."' WHERE ID='".$IDllista."' ") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO vots (IDllista, IDusuari) VALUES ($IDllista, $IDusuari)");
```

When I upload the page the new punctuation is there, the problem is just to get the ajax response. Thanks for your help, and sorry if it's a silly question, I'm pretty new!

Comment: In your PHP code, avoide the use of mysql_* functions and use mysqli instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ajax's `success` parameter:

```
$.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             data: { action: action, llista: llista}, 
             url: 'like.php',
             success: function(response) { alert(response); }
         });
   });
```

Comment: Note that this is deprecated in > 1.8; use .done, .fail, .always instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use the short-method for $.ajax:

```
$.post(url, {action: action, llista: llista}, function(data_from_server) {
    console.log(data_from_server);
});
```